# Excel VBA crashes by changing the value on a cell

Tags: excel, vba

i am new here and try to learn VBA Excel but it doesn't work.

I want a function with one paramter to insert by each cell an increased value.

```
Option Explicit

Function DefineAI(rngToSet As Range) As String
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim cell As Range

    On Error GoTo Fehler
    Let intCounter = 1
    For Each cell In rngToSet.Cel
        'cell.Value = intCounter         'Test 1: It crashes with no error
        Range(cell).Value = intCounter   'Test 2: It crashes with no error
        intCounter = intCounter + 1      'intCounter++ ?? not important yet
    Next

    DefineAI = "test"
    Exit Function
Fehler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Function
```

It crashes on two different Computers with no Error!
Actually it doesn't crash, but just stop.

I have also try with a sub, but the same result.

Comment: hmm. some things to change: 1. `for each cell in rngtoset` 2. `cell.value=intcounter` 3. omit the `let`

Comment: I have it changed as described above, but it doesn't always work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the value of another cell with a UDF `Function` and cannot call a `Sub` from within a UDF `Function` that changes the value of another cell. If you are looking to run a macro that will perform what you wish then here is some code that runs.

```
Sub mcr_Call_DefineAI()
    Call mcr_DefineAI(Range("D2:D10"))
End Sub

Private Sub mcr_DefineAI(rngToSet As Range, Optional iSTART As Long = 1)
    Dim i As Long, r As Range

    On Error GoTo Fehler
    i = iSTART
    For Each r In rngToSet
        r = i
        i = i + 1
    Next

    Debug.Print "Test funktionierte!"
    Exit Sub
Fehler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

I've included an optional parameter so you can change the starting number of the increment.

Answer (score 1):

You've declare `cell` as a Range, then pass it into a Range. The problem is that Range expects a string representing the address of a cell. So, you get a runtime error.

> ```
>    Range(cell).Value = intCounter   'Test 2: It crashes with no error
> ```

To fix it, just set the value of `cell`.

```
cell.Value = intCounter
```

---

I also noticed this comment.

> ```
>  'intCounter++ ?? not important yet
> ```

You should know that VBA does not have an increment operator. You have incremented your variable correctly.

```
intCounter = intCounter + 1
```

That's just how it's done in VBA. (And yes, it kinda sucks.)

Comment: But it doesn't work with **cell.Value = intCounter** too.
The problem was the UDF.., thanks for helping!